JLPCB Design Rules for Altium CircuitMaker
What is the right design rules from JLCPCB?
When I look at the electrical clearance from JLCPCB, I find:

Via to Via (Same net labels): 0.254mm
Hole to hole (Different net labels): 0.5mm
Pad to pad (Different net labels): 0.127mm
Pad to Pad with hole (Different net labels): 0.5mm
Via to track: 0.254 mm
Plated Hole to track: 0.33mm
Non Plated Hole to track: 0.254mm
Pad to track: 0.2mm
Minimum spacning: 0.09mm (4-6 layers)

https://jlcpcb.com/capabilities/pcb-capabilities
Question:
Are these the correct settings of the design rules?

Issue:
The issue is that it seems like a regular BGA footprint cannot even be produced by JLCPCB with those design rules. I have downloaded a sample CAD model from STMicroelectronics and it seems that all the rules from that model violate the JLCPCB rules. Is that correct?

are you entering the parameters in the correct units?

@JasenСлаваУкраїні yes, in mm.

You would stand a better chance of getting a good answer if you included an image the proposed BGA footprint. I don't think anyone is going to go to a registration-walled site and install a footprint just to answer this question.

Yes!
The answer is that JLCPCB can produce that CAD-model.
I uploaded the gerber files of that CAD-model and load it into JLCPCB and ask them for review the gerber files.
Approved, from their side.
